# What would be the most appropriate way for a website to know that a form has already been submitted?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I can't explain what I want to do in the correct terminology but I'll give an example.

A website has on most pages a 'quick contact' form in a sidebar. Once the form is submitted on any given page that contains it, it fades and a confirmation message appears. How can I allow the website to identify that the form has already been submitted and then just display the confirmation message on all areas which would have contained it (throughout the whole site). Ideally, this would only occur for a limited period of set time (such as after 1 day or close of browser it resets and the form is present when that specific user access' the website again.

Honestly, I have no idea where to even start with this, but an **important thing to note** is that the form submission is just a 'dummy submission' and is not actually sending any data to the server (I know this is wrong but this task has the specific requirement of predominately client side access).

Edit: A cookie was what I was after.

Comment: Handle the submitted form. Store a flag in cookie. If flag is true then display message otherwise display the form.

Comment: What you are describing sounds exactly like: cookies!

Comment: I thought I could use a cookie but wasn't sure! All good, I'll have a look into them. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options to store flags in the client-side, like cookies and local storage to name a few. If this functionality is bound to a user account, you can also set a flag in the DB table or column that's related to that user.

Comment: Excuse my lack of knowledge, but what exactly is a flag

Comment: @homer5677 Something (a variable, db field, etc) where you can store a value and pick it up later to indicate something.